# Initializing a class only when user signs up for the first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, initialization

I'm working on a Rails application that when the user signs up for the first time with facebook omniauth a new wardrobe will be created for that user.

I have two possible files that I think would work. I'll label the place I think

```
@wardrobe = Wardrobe.new
@wardrobe.save!
```

will work with a 'xx'

I suspect it must be in the User model when the user is first created using omniauth:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :likes
has_many :outfits
has_one :wardrobe

def self.from_omniauth(auth_hash)
  where(auth_hash.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    user.provider = auth_hash.provider
    user.uid = auth_hash.uid
    user.name = auth_hash.info.name
    user.email = auth_hash.info.email
    user.image = auth_hash.info.image
    user.oauth_token = auth_hash.credentials.token
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth_hash.credentials.expires_at)
    user.save!
  end
  xx
end
```

end

I also thought about putting it in the Sessions controller when the user creates a session but wouldn't that create a new Wardrobe each time they sign in:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def create
  @user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  xx
  session[:current_user] = @user
  session[:user_id] = @user.id
  redirect_to wardrobe_index_path 
end
def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_url
end

protected

  def auth_hash
    request.env['omniauth.auth'] 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save state of user record(whether it new record or not) in local variable or create callback.

Example with callback:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_wardrobe
end
```

Example with check in `from_omniauth` method:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth_hash)
  where(auth_hash.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    create_wardrobe = user.new_record?
    user.provider = auth_hash.provider
    user.uid = auth_hash.uid
    user.name = auth_hash.info.name
    user.email = auth_hash.info.email
    user.image = auth_hash.info.image
    user.oauth_token = auth_hash.credentials.token
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth_hash.credentials.expires_at)
    user.save!
  end
  user.wardrope.create! if create_wardrobe
  user
end
```

Also, I think that so huge methods lead to fat models. Hence I suggest you to extract `from_omniaut` method to a service.

Comment: Although I'm sure this could work I didn't know how to implement the new_record? method. Thank you for the help though!

Comment: I ended up taking your advice. And for some reason I only needed to put `after_create :create_wardrobe` in user.rb. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, that's because `has_one` relation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one

Answer (score 1):

if `@user` `has_one :wardrobe`, why not simply create a wardrobe when one is not referenced by `@user`?

```
@wardrobe = @user.wardrobe
unless @wardrobe
  @wardrobe = Wardrobe.new
  @wardrobe.save!
  @user.wardrobe = @wardrobe
end
```

Comment: I put this into my sessions controller and it worked well so far. Thank you!